# Error installing dl4j using maven

Tags: maven, jfreechart, dl4j

Sorry but I am very new to using Maven, trying to install dl4j for the provided examples via the following command, as per the instructions on the dl4j website:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

This proceeds somewhat, but then terminates with an error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project dl4j-examples: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/nick/Downloads/dl4j-examples/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/unsupervised/variational/plot/PlotUtil.java:[158,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method setDomainPannable(boolean)
[ERROR]   location: variable plot of type org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot
[ERROR] /Users/nick/Downloads/dl4j-examples/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/unsupervised/variational/plot/PlotUtil.java:[159,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method setRangePannable(boolean)
[ERROR]   location: variable plot of type org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Now I have jfreechart library in a directory searchable by classpath, so, can someone help me resolve the above?

Running mac high sierra, on a 2016 macbook pro.

Comment: Sounds like this is related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project?rq=1

Comment: See also [*Building JFreeChart*](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart#building-jfreechart).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to build/install dl4j to run the examples. 
Straight from the [dl4j quickstart](https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/deeplearning4j-quickstart):

```
git clone https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples.git
cd dl4j-examples/
mvn clean install
```